# python, Django - private media streaming and prevent hijacking

Tags: python, django, video-streaming

I'm using **python 2.7** and **Django 1.7** .

I need **private streaming** for project medias such as **video and image** and preventing from any **hijack**.

Do you know any modules or some thing else for this?

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways and formats to get video streaming.

I don't know anything ready to use for live video streams, but if you just going to serve `.mp4` files and images, you can check the permissions on django side and then serve the content from nginx

https://wellfire.co/blog/nginx-django-x-accel-redirects/

or https://github.com/johnsensible/django-sendfile